# How do you draw a line between points in matlab?

Tags: matlab, graph, matplotlib, plot

I'm looking to create a "web" between a set of points where the data tells whether there is a link between any two points.

The way I thought of would be by plotting every couple points, and overlaying each couple on top of eachother.

However, if there is a way to just simple draw a line between two points that would be much easier.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can organize the x and y coordinates of your line segments into 2-by-N arrays, you can use the function [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) to plot each column of the matrices as a line. Here's a simple example to draw the four lines of a unit square:

```
x = [0 1 1 0; ...
     1 1 0 0];
y = [0 0 1 1; ...
     0 1 1 0];
plot(x,y);
```

This will plot each line in a different color. To plot all of the lines as black, do this:

```
plot(x,y,'k');
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html). Suppose your two points are `a = [x1 y1]` and `b = [x2 y2]`, then:

```
plot([x1 x2],[y1 y2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you meant by `I'm looking to create a "web" between a set of points where the data tells whether there is a link between any two points` actually some kind of `graph` represented by its adjacency matrix (opposite to other answers simple means to connect points), then:

this [gplot function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/gplot.html) may indeed be the proper tool for you. It's the basic visualization tool to plot nodes and links of a `graph` represented as a adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 2):

use this function:

```
function [] = drawline(p1, p2 ,color)
%enter code here
theta = atan2( p2(2) - p1(2), p2(1) - p1(1));
r = sqrt( (p2(1) - p1(1))^2 + (p2(2) - p1(2))^2);
line = 0:0.01: r;
x = p1(1) + line*cos(theta);
y = p1(2) + line*sin(theta);
plot(x, y , color)
```

call it like:

```
drawline([fx(i) fy(i)] ,[y(i,1) y(i,2)],'red')
```

Credit: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/108652-draw-lines-between-points#answer_139175

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you want a line with coordinates (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). Then you make a vector with the x and y coordinates: **x = [x1 x2]** and **y=[y1 y2]**.
Matlab has a function called 'Line', this is used in this way: 
**line(x,y)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the effect of drawing lines, you can use `plot` inside `for` loop note that `data` is a n*2 matrix containing the 'x,y' of 'n' points

```
clf(figure(3))
for i = 1 : length(data)-1
 plot([data(i,1),data(i+1,1)], [data(i,2),data(i+1,2)], '-*');
 hold on
end
hold off
```

Or can use this statement to draw it in one step

```
plot(data(:,1), data(:,2), '-*');
```